# how to display multiple images in php from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I used the following code to upload the images. It works well. But I dont know how to display all the images in a display page.

Please help for the code for display.

```
    <?php
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }       
    $query="INSERT into upload_data (`USER_ID`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) 
            VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";

    $desired_dir="gallery";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"gallery/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="gallery/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());          
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
 }
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Before you write *any* more SQL code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid serious [SQL escaping bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You **cannot** use string interpolation to compose queries. It's also a bad idea to be using `mysql_query` as it's deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can show images something like this:

```
$sql="select * from tbl_image";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$image=$row ['photo'];

echo '<img src="path/'.$image.'" width="360" height="150">';

}
```

Comment: What's up with all the error-suppressing? Terrible for debugging

Comment: the fact you have edited your code doesn't mean much. Is there a reason behind the fact you are suppressing even a variable declaration with the `@` sign? Are you aware of it's purpose?

Comment: Yes I know the purpose of it. It temporarily sets the error reporting level to 0 for that line. If that line triggers an error, the error handler will still be called, but it will be called with an error level of 0.

I sometimes use it while testing some scripts, but it's better to not show it him that way. You guys are right.

Comment: It dos n't shows any error. But image not displayed. Image border displays for all images, but image shows like unavailable or broken image.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result= //select query for retrieving filenames for a particular userid 
         //or all depending upon your requirement.

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo "<div><img src=\"gallery/".$row['filename']."\" /></div>"
}
```